# Inverse Laplace Transform of $e^{-x\sqrt{s}}/\left[\left(s-a^2\right)\left(\sqrt{s}+a\right)\right]$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I'm interested in the following Laplace inversion problem
$$f(t,x)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{e^{-x\sqrt{s}}}{\left(s-a^2\right)\left(\sqrt{s}+a\right)}\right\}$$
with $a$ real and positive, as appears in Eq. (2) of [Phys. Rev. E 96, 023104](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.96.023104) (a pdf can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318530014_Effect_of_advection_on_transient_ion_concentration-polarization_phenomenon)).
In that article, the authors mention the following early-time approximation
$$f(t,x)=2\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}e^{-x^2/4t}-x{\rm Erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}}\right),$$
but do not solve the full Laplace inversion problem. Any suggestions on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using partial fractions and realising that $1/(s-a)$ is the Laplace transform of $e^{a t}$ should help. If you know the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-x\sqrt{x}}$ (I suppose it will be some one-sided Levy distribution), then immediately, in time domain, $f(t,x)$ is the convolution of the the Levy distribution and two exponentials.

Comment: In the comment above, I meant $e^{-x\sqrt{s}}$. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

With CAS like: **Maple 2022** I have:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{e^{-x\sqrt{s}}}{\left(s-a^2\right)\left(\sqrt{s}+a\right)}\right\}=\\\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}\, {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{x^{2}}{4 t}}+\frac{-\mathrm{erfc}\! \left(\frac{2 a t +x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right) {\mathrm e}^{a \left(a t +x \right)} \left(4 a^{2} t +2 a x +1\right)+\mathrm{erfc}\! \left(-\frac{2 a t -x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right) {\mathrm e}^{a \left(a t -x \right)}}{4 a}
$$
for $x>0$.

Maple code:

`(t/Pi)^(1/2)*exp(-1/4*x^2/t)+1/4*(-erfc(1/2*(2*a*t+x)/t^(1/2))*exp(a*(a*t+x))*( 4*a^2*t+2*a*x+1)+erfc(-1/2*(2*a*t-x)/t^(1/2))*exp(a*(a*t-x)))/a`

`

Comment: I'm wondering how it came up with that monstrosity